# function pointer to Child vs Parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

I'm learning C++ and I keep getting a weird compilation error I don't understand. I simplified my code to the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    static A foo()
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }
};

class B : A
{
public:
    static B boo()
    {
        B b;
        return b;
    }
};

typedef A (*function)(void);

int main() {
    function f1 = A::foo;
    function f2 = B::boo; //error
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot initialize a variable of type 'function' (aka 'A (*)()') with an lvalue of type 'B ()': different return type ('A' vs 'B')

Would anyone be able to explain why it doesn't work? Since `B` is a child of `A`, `B` is `A`, why is a function pointer from "void to `B`" isn't like a function pointer from "void to `A`"?

Comment: The return types are different. B is not A

Comment: Apart from the answers, nobody in the whole program knows that `B` inherits from `A`, because default access modifier for `class` is `private`. You need `class B: public A`

Answer (score 4):

Your `function` claims that it should return an `A` but `boo` returns a `B`, so:

```
typedef A (*A_function)();
typedef B (*B_function)();

int main() {
    A_function f1 = A::foo;
    B_function f2 = B::boo;
}
```

---

You could possibly solve it by returning a base class pointer from both functions:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;      // for destruction via a base class pointer

    static A* foo() { return new A; }
};

class B : A { // you should probably use public inheritance
public:
    static A* boo() { return new B; } // creates a B but returns an A*
};

typedef A* (*function)();

int main() {
    function f1 = A::foo;
    function f2 = B::boo;
}
```

---

Or better, using smart pointers to not have to `delete` instances manually:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;

    static std::unique_ptr<A> foo() { return std::make_unique<A>(); }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<A> boo() { return std::make_unique<B>(); }
};

using function = std::unique_ptr<A>(*)();

int main() {
    function f1 = A::foo;
    function f2 = B::boo;
}
```

Comment: This scratches all of my itches, well done!

Answer (score 4):

It is true that C++ allows a pointer to a child class to get converted to a pointer to the parent class (subject to certain conditions).

It is also true that C++ allows a reference to a child class to get converted to a reference to the parent class (also subject to certain conditions).

However, that does not mean that C++ allows a pointer to a function that returns a parent class to be converted to a pointer to a function that returns the child class. This is what the shown code is trying to do, and that is not allowed.

That answer your question of "why": because this is not allowed in C++. As far as why, the "why"; that's mostly due to some practical considerations, but that's immaterial, that's just not allowed by the rules of C++.

Comment: As for the practical considerations, consider the case where `B` has an added data member to `A`.  Now the copy constructors for the two classes will be different; which should the compiler call and how would it choose?

Answer (score 0):

> Since `B` is a child of `A`, `B` is `A`,

Not quite. Since `B` is a child of `A`, any `B` object is also an `A` object. However, this is not symmetric, so it is overstating the case to claim that `B` is `A`. It is correct to claim "a `B` is an `A`", but dropping the indefinite articles ("a" and "an") makes the claim false.

> why is a function pointer from "void to `B`" isn't like a function pointer from "void to `A`"?

Because `B` is not `A`. The return types are different, so the function types are different. A `B` object can be converted to an `A` object (by copying the `A` sub-object), but that is an extra step. If you were to write

```cpp
A value = B::boo();
```

then the compiler inserts a conversion from `B` to `A` after `boo()` is called. The conversion might not require machine instructions (a.k.a. a "no-op"), but it is there nonetheless. (One side-effect of having a conversion is that copying cannot be [elided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).)

```cpp
A value = static_cast<A&&>(B::boo());
```

If you were to invoke `boo()` through a function pointer of the type `A(*)()`, there would be nothing to tell the compiler to insert the conversion. Skipping the conversion could be an issue, particularly if a `B` object had data members not in `A` objects, especially if those data members had non-trivial destructors.

The language does not attempt to draw a line between the cases where skipping the conversion is and is not a problem. This applies to both the return type and the parameter types. The type of a function assigned to a pointer must match the pointer's type exactly, no conversions needed.

---

This is where function objects, like `std::function`, are useful. A `std::function<A()>` could store either `A:foo` or `B::boo`. This is because the function object will adapt and record what conversions are needed, similar to what happens when invoking a function directly. Unlike a function pointer, a function object does not require an exact match on types.